# ";" invalid token and velocity is not a defined "Object"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, token

I'm learning Unity and I have begun the second tutorial "Space Shooter". The Tutorial was designed on a previous engine version and now it is out of date. They offered a new fix for the code as stated below.

> "In Unity 5 and later we can no longer access components using their “shorthand helper references” and we must access them directly using “GetComponent”. One example of this is accessing the Rigidbody component attached to the same GameObject as the script.
>
> In Unity 4 and earlier, this was simply accessed with “rigidbody.” Now this must be done with “GetComponent().”
>
> It is usually a “best practice” to find this Component when the instance of the script initializes, and “cache” the reference in a local variable.
>
> This is commonly written as:
>
> ```
> private Rigidbody;
>
> void Start ()
> {
>     rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
> }
> ```
>
> Now, with the reference to the local Rigidbody component saved in the variable “rb”, we can use this reference anywhere within the script."

**Below is my code and my attempt to alter the original code that determines simple player movement. I have no idea how they want me to fix it as this is literally my second exposure to coding. I'm getting choked up on the rigidbody ";" token and the rb.velocity part.**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private object rb;
    private Rigidbody

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f,moveVertical);
        rb.velocity = movement;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is `private Rigidbody rb;` get rid of the object line.

Comment: Also, start with the Roll-A-Ball tutorial. it is more updated to the modern version of Unity.

Comment: Also if you plan on learning Unity and using C#, it's a good idea to take a look at some programming tutorials before getting started with the Unity engine.

Answer (score 1):

For starters I would like to advice you to follow some basic tutorials on [C#](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/) as it seems you are not properly understanding it yet. Just learning the basics should take you a few days at most, but will allow you to fix problems such as this by your self fairly easily.

Now lets take a look at what you are actually doing wrong.

The first variable you are defining is.

```
private object rb;
```

This exists of 4 sections

- Access Modifier (Private)
- Type (object)
- Name (rb)
- Line ending (;)

This is what a proper variable declaration looks like, so that is good.

Now, the second variable declaration however seems to miss quite a bit.

```
private Rigidbody
```

As you only want a `Rigidbody` to begin with, we can combine the 2 variables into 1 variable.

```
private Rigidbody rb;
```

Now we have 1 complete variable, which we can use. And because we did not change the `rb`, we don't need to change any other code!